# Activity ShortCut is not create in Vivo devices

Tags: android

I want to create the Activity shortcut on the home screen, so a user can open the activity screen directly .

I have used this code

```
if(ShortcutManagerCompat.isRequestPinShortcutSupported
    (getApplicationContext()))
    {
        ShortcutInfoCompat shortcut = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), id)
         .setIntent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
           TranslateActivity.class).setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN))
         .setShortLabel(label)
         .setIcon(icon)
         .build();
        return 
         ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut(getApplicationContext(), 
         shortcut, startHomeScreen());
    }
    else
    {
        // Shortcut is not supported by your launcher
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TranslateActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Test");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    }
```

Comment: this code is working for all version devices but not working in Vivo v11.

Comment: Any logcat would help to understand the problem

Comment: no, nothing is error  in logcat also.

Comment: hi @ZubairYounas geting this error **Calling application must have a foreground activity**

Comment: Calling application must have a foreground activity or a foreground service

Comment: Yes exactly, You have to add a service in order to create shortcut when your app is in backrgound. If it is already in foreground, then check the context you are using. i.e. `getApplicationContext()` might be null when you are getting it.

Comment: yes also try using creating  with service but then nothing is happening  and still get the ture on result @ZubairYounas

Comment: @ZubairYounas can you share code if you have

Comment: did you any solution?

Comment: @bhavin still not working on some of Vivo devices

Answer (score 0):

**It's because of default launcher in vivo devices**. When I changed default launcher to some other launcher It's let me create desktop shortcut. So as far I did R&d I found below solution it's not complete solution but you can redirect to allow Desktop shortcuts screen.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
intent.component = ComponentName("com.bbk.launcher2", "com.bbk.launcher2.installshortcut.PurviewActivity")
activity.startActivity(intent)
```

### I tried to get result if user allowed or not but it's not work for all vivo devices.

```
var uri = Uri.parse("content://com.bbk.launcher2.settings/favorites")
            var query = activity.contentResolver.query(uri, null, " itemType = ?", arrayOf("30"), null);
            if (query != null && query.count > 0) {
                var idIndex = query.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
                var intentIndex = query.getColumnIndexOrThrow("intent");
                var shortcutPermissionIndex = query.getColumnIndexOrThrow("shortcutPermission");
                while (query.moveToNext()) {
                    val long = query.getLong(idIndex)
                    val intent = query.getString(intentIndex)
                    val shortcutPermission = query.getInt(shortcutPermissionIndex)
                    var unflattenFromString = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(intent)
                    Log.e("bhavin->", "initView: getShortcutPerBtn id=$long packageName= ${unflattenFromString!!.packageName} shortcutPermission= $shortcutPermission")
                    if (unflattenFromString!!.packageName == activity.packageName && shortcutPermission != 0 && shortcutPermission != 16){
                        val intent = Intent()
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        intent.component = ComponentName("com.bbk.launcher2", "com.bbk.launcher2.installshortcut.PurviewActivity")
                        activity.startActivity(intent)
                        query.close()
                        return@ensureBackgroundThread
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.e("bhavin->","abcd")
                    }
                }
                query.close()
            }
```

For more details you can check this I found this [git](https://github.com/bhavin-qfonapp/UiLibrary/tree/master/ShortCut)

Note: I found exception some devices vivo 1902 and Z3

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.bbk.launcher2.data.LauncherProvider from ProcessRecord{f8f30af 16137:com.qiutinghe.change/u0a172} (pid=16137, uid=10172)
requires com.bbk.launcher2.permission.READ_SETTINGS or com.bbk.launcher2.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
```